# How to import a module to a class in intelliJ?

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, import, module

I need to use a module from a class in java, intellij. I have already done the: File | New | Module from Existing Sources, but I don't know how to use this module from the class. Should i call it in a certain way or assign something to it? Thanks for your help and sorry for my lack of expertise, this is my first time using intellij

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one module as a dependency to another. See [Module dependency](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html) doc page.
After that, you could call a class as `<package name>.<Class name>` in the module with dependency.